# SQLite for returning only duplicate rows

Tags: sqlite

I have a SQL like the following -

```
select a.id as metadata_item_id , b.id as media_parts_id from media_items b 
join metadata_items a on a.id = b.metadata_item_id
where a.library_section_id = 2 and a.metadata_type = 4 and a.deleted_at is NULL
```

However, I want only rows with duplicate `a.id` to be returned, and only one instance of each.  I know in sql I can use rank_order() and return all rows where rank=2 but couldn't find something like that for SQLite.  How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Recent enough sqlite (3.25 or newer) supports window functions like `rank()` or `row_number()`, btw.

Answer (score 0):

You can `group by a.id` and use a `having` clause to check for duplicates:

```
select a.id as metadata_item_id
from media_items b join metadata_items a 
on a.id = b.metadata_item_id
where a.library_section_id = 2 and a.metadata_type = 4 and a.deleted_at is NULL
group by a.id
having count(*) > 1
```

If you want also the column `b.id` in the results, you will have only 1 value, so you can use aggregation like `MIN` or `MAX`:

```
select a.id as metadata_item_id, max(b.id) as media_parts_id
from media_items b join metadata_items a 
on a.id = b.metadata_item_id
where a.library_section_id = 2 and a.metadata_type = 4 and a.deleted_at is NULL
group by a.id
having count(*) > 1
```

or use simply `b.id`, since SQLite allows non aggregated columns in the select list, to get an arbitrary value of `b.id`.

Comment: In SQLite, can you do `WHERE id IN (...a subquery...)`?  If so, that subquery could be a query which, using `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`, only returned `id`'s which occur more than one time.  I know that's how I'd do it in other SQLs but offhand I don't remember if SQLite supports that.

Comment: `WHERE id IN (...a subquery...)` is SQL standard, so of course it is valid in SQLite.